# A way to reset the content when the modal is closed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Having this modal which has some inputs which are validated with react-hook-form:

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';

import { Modal, Footer, Input, Textarea } from '../ui-components';

import { usePostData } from '../lib/hooks/use-post-data';
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  input: yup.string(),
  description: yup.string()
});

export interface MyModalProps {
  open: boolean;
  toggle: () => void;
}

export function MyModal({ open, toggle }: MyModalProps) {
  const emptyInput = {
    input: '',
    description: ''
  };
  const { handleSubmit, reset, register } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const { mutate: postDta } = usePostData();

  const onAddSubmit = (data) => {
    postSignalMapping(data);
    toggle();
    reset(emptyInput);
  };

 const onCancelModal = () => {
    toggle();
    reset(emptyInput);
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      title='my modal'
      open={open}
      onClose={toggle}
      footer={<Footer onSubmit={handleSubmit(onAddSubmit)} onCancel={onCancelModal} />}
    >
      <div>
        <Input inputId='input' label='input' {...register('input')} />
        <Textarea label='description' {...register('description')} />
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default MyModal;
```

It works pretty well beside the `reset` part which must be done when the modal is closed, it has some bugs sometimes.

Is there a way to make it re-render after the modal is closed?

Comment: What is the sometimes bug? What is the issue? Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: "sometimes", after submitting, if I open the modal, the data introduced before is still there

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to also provide default values to the `useForm` hook.

[`reset` docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset)

- You will need to pass `defaultValues` to `useForm` in order to reset the `Controller` components' value.
- When invoking `reset({ value })` without supplying `defaultValues` via `useForm`, the library will replace `defaultValues` with a shallow clone `value` object which you provide **(not deepClone)**.

  ```
   // ❌ avoid the following with deep nested default values
   const defaultValues = { object: { deepNest: { file: new File() } } };
   useForm({ defaultValues });
   reset(defaultValues); // share the same reference

   // ✅ it's safer with the following, as we only doing shallow clone with defaultValues
   useForm({ deepNest: { file: new File() } });
   reset({ deepNest: { file: new File() } });
  ```

Use the spread syntax to create shallow copies of the `emptyInput` default values object.

```
export function MyModal({ open, toggle }: MyModalProps) {
  const emptyInput = {
    input: '',
    description: ''
  };

  const { handleSubmit, reset, register } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { ...emptyInput },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  ...

  const onAddSubmit = (data) => {
    postSignalMapping(data);
    toggle();
    reset({ ...emptyInput });
  };

 const onCancelModal = () => {
    toggle();
    reset({ ...emptyInput });
  };

  ...
}
```